# How to print the position coordinates of the html screen in console while scrolling using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner and how to print the height of the HTML page considering the starting point of the page and end point like coordinate in Console using Basic Javascript only. while scrolling the page changes so it needs to calculate the scrolling also.
i tried with these codes

> script.js

```
document.body.onload = function(s) {

    s = s || window.event;
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    console.log(["Width: " + w + "<br>Height: " + h]);
}
```

and

```
function getScrollXY() {

    var scrOfX = 0, scrOfY = 0;
    if( typeof( window.pageYOffset ) == 'number' ) {

        //Netscape compliant
        scrOfY = window.pageYOffset;
        scrOfX = window.pageXOffset;

    } 
    else if( document.body && ( document.body.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollTop ) ) {

        //DOM compliant
        scrOfY = document.body.scrollTop;
        scrOfX = document.body.scrollLeft;

    }
    else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollTop ) ) {

        //IE6 standards compliant mode
        scrOfY = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        scrOfX = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;

    }
    return [ scrOfX, scrOfY ];
}
```

but these won't works. help me to correct my code.

Comment: `but these won't works` what exactly not working? Seems Ok for me: http://jsbin.com/farusiy/edit?js,console,output

Comment: required output is not printed in console. i need output like the X(top) and Y(bottom) co-ordinate of the height ( it will change if we scroll the page). And to print the first and last element of that html page

Comment: `of the height ` height of what? `And to print the first and last element of that html page` do you mean, the first and the last **visible** elements? (e.g. the elements in the viewport). Can you create a **working** [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [bin](http://jsbin.com) for this?

Comment: height of the page. yes i had created a working snippet. ( e.g. if i have first line of the current html as "i am....." and last line as "thank you" i need to print first and last element as "first=i and last=u" . with the top and bottom position of the page as height

Comment: `i had created a working snippe` Where? Can you share it?